# Cannot manage redirect

Tags: c#

I'm trying to manage the redirect on this site: `https://uk.soccerway.com`, so I wrote this code:

```
public static string GetHtml(string url)
{
        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        try
        {
            webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;                
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            url = (response.Headers["Location"] != null) ? response.Headers["Location"] : url;
            return client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

this will return an Exception, in particular:

> 'The remote server returned an error: (302) Moved Temporarily.'

what I did wrong?

Comment: what is your _storedData ?

Comment: @Vietvo sorry I fix the question, essentially I return the html source

Comment: I implemented your code and everything works well. Could you give me a link example that make a "302 error" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see this being a useful answer for many other users so reading [this article](https://long2know.com/2016/07/capturing-redirects-with-httpclient/) helped me arrive with the code below. It recursively handles the redirects in case there are more than 1 redirects. Finally it returns the response:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage MakeRequest(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        var statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

        // We want to handle redirects ourselves so that we can 
        // determine the final redirect Location (via header)
        if (statusCode >= 300 && statusCode <= 399)
        {
            var redirectUri = response.Headers.Location;
            if (!redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            {
                redirectUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.
                    GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + redirectUri);
            }

            return MakeRequest(redirectUri.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
HttpResponseMessage response = MakeRequest("https://uk.soccerway.com");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: what's _timeout?

Comment: Gets or sets the number of milliseconds to wait before the request times out. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: ok but I don't understood well how can I retrieve the html source using a webclient if the method will call itself again on `MakeRequest(redirectUri);`

Comment: Sorry I looked at that code and it was poorly written. I have modified the code. It should work now.